# Iterate over set of csv files in R to produce series of jpg

Tags: r, ggplot2, iteration

I have a bunch of csv files produces by a Python code. The files are named

```
new_pareto_1.csv, new_pareto_2.csv, new_pareto_3.csv, etc.
```

and

```
new_paretoF_1.csv, new_paretoF_2.csv, new_paretoF_3.csv, etc.
```

I need to adapt my code so that all pairs of files are sequentially plotted with this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.csv("/new_pareto_1.csv", check.names = FALSE)

dat2 <- read.csv("/new_paretoF_1.csv", check.names = FALSE)

dat$modu = dat$modu
dat$mnc = dat$mnc
dat$eff = dat$eff

dat2$modu = dat2$modu
dat2$mnc = dat2$mnc
dat2$eff = dat2$eff

res2 <- do.call(rbind, combn(1:2, 2, function(ii)
        cbind(setNames(dat2[,c(ii, setdiff(1:2, ii))], c("x", "y")),
              var=paste(names(dat2)[ii], collapse="/")), simplify=F))


res <- do.call(rbind, combn(1:2, 2, function(ii)
  cbind(row=seq(nrow(dat)),setNames(dat[,c(ii, setdiff(1:2, ii))], c("x", "y")),
        var=paste(names(dat)[ii], collapse="/")), simplify=F))

ggplot(res, aes(x=x, y=y, color=row))+ geom_point(shape=4, alpha = .9) +
geom_line(data = res2, aes(x=x, y=y), colour = "black") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"Spectral")))+
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales="free") +
  scale_y_continuous("y", limits = c(0.38, .5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("x", limits = c(.25, .75))
```

And saved to a bunch of jpg files called:

```
solutions_1.jpg, solutions_2.jpg, solutions_3.jpg, etc.
```

How to achieve this in R?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loop that will read a pair of files, process them  and write a jpeg and then do the same for each successive pair of files. I haven't tested the code below, since I don't have sample data to work with:

```
# Vectors with the names of the two file groups we want to work with
fg1 = list.files(pattern="new_pareto_[0-9]*\\.csv")
fg2 = list.files(pattern="new_paretoF_[0-9]*\\.csv")

# Loop over each pair of files
for (i in 1:length(fg1)) {

  dat = read.csv(fg1[i])
  dat2 = read.csv(fg2[i])

  ... processing steps ...

  p = ggplot(res, aes(x=x, y=y, color=row))+ geom_point(shape=4, alpha = .9) +
    geom_line(data = res2, aes(x=x, y=y), colour = "black") +
    scale_color_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"Spectral")))+
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales="free") +
    scale_y_continuous("y", limits = c(0.38, .5)) +
    scale_x_continuous("x", limits = c(.25, .75))

  # Get file number
  num = gsub(".*_([0-9]*).*", "\\1", fg1[i])

  # Write to jpeg file. Set width and height to desired values.
  jpeg(paste0("solutions_", num, ".jpg"), 800, 600)
  p
  dev.off()
}
```